# Client application is receiving message body in different format from IBM-MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, jms-topic

The message format is coming differently in our client's environment with the same code base that we have in our dev / vendor regions.
This is causing us parsing issues while loading the key/value pairs.
I want to know why the message format is different? Is there some Queue related setting / config which is different and may cause this behavior?

**Message published to the Broker (IBM-MQ):**

```
JMSMessage class: jms_map
  JMSType:          null
  JMSDeliveryMode:  2
  JMSExpiration:    0
  JMSPriority:      4
  JMSMessageID:     ID:414d5120415533434754312e4d5120205ac293cd2beede03
  JMSTimestamp:     1522811298693
  JMSCorrelationID: null
  JMSDestination:   topic:TESTTOPICNAME
  JMSReplyTo:       null
  JMSRedelivered:   false
    JMSXAppID: WebSphere MQ Client for Java
    JMSXDeliveryCount: 0
    JMSXUserID: aubdpmqadsa 
    JMS_IBM_ConnectionID: 414D5143415533434754312E4D5120205AC293CD2BEEDC01
    JMS_IBM_PutApplType: 28
    JMS_IBM_PutDate: 20180404
    JMS_IBM_PutTime: 03081872
correlationId = 1234567890
status = Pending
objectId= 123
name= MLS
```

**In Dev / Vendor Env:**
**Message Body received from the Broker (IBM-MQ):**

{status=Pending, name=Testing, objectId=123, correlationId=1234567890}

**In CLIENT's environment:**

**Message Body received from the Broker (IBM-MQ):**
This is the issue why it is getting the map in my client's environment whereas in our dev / vendor's test regions it is more of a JSON key/value format.

```
<map>
    <correlationId>1234567890</correlationId>
    <status>Pending</status>
    <objectId>123</objectId>
    <name>Testing</name>
</map>
```

Comment: What library are you using to read the message in the 2 environment? MQ Java classes for JMS represent JMS map messages as XML, so I think that JSON is produced by some further processing.

Comment: If you're using Message Broker, perhaps you have a message flow in one environment that is converting the message structure from the XML form to the JSON form, after all that is exactly what MB is for. To determine whether the message structure is converted before it it put onto the queue, browse the queue with the amqsbcg sample that comes with MQ. If it is the same in both environments, then you know something in the getting application is converting it. If it is different in the two environments then something is changing it earlier in the flow.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi : We are using the same code base / libs in both environments. 

    org.apache.camel.Message msg = exchange.getIn();
    Map<String, String> msgMap= msg.getBody(Map.class);